# Vitamio media player onCompletion Listner not called

Tags: android

I am using vitamio SDK I have written the code like below but onCompletion listener is not called.

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this);
            Utils.showLog(TAG, "Alert video path to be play : " + path);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(sholder);
            mediaPlayer.setBufferSize(1024 * 256);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


            mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
```

and set the onCompletion listener after start of the video

```
 mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```

Comment: Can you share your imports?

Comment: import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer;

Comment: Are you setting the onCompletionListener before playing or during? Have you tried before playing the video?

Comment: Have you tried anonymous listener?

Comment: I had tried but not get any success

Answer (score 0):

`setOnCompletionListener` on `VideoView` instead of `MediaPlayer`.

```
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                VideoPlayerActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
```

**Update**

I think problem is with your imports.
Double check following import.

`import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;`

Comment: sory i had to use media player , i using media player for other functionality also. So its better if you have any solution with media Player

Comment: sorry i used only with VideoView. best of luck.

Comment: Have you imported `io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;`